# Visualforce Tab: how to edit the link (Content)

Tags: customization, tab, visualforce-tab

I want to edit the link for my visualforce tab. So i go to the `Setup -> Create -> Tabs` and click on the `Edit` next to my custom tab name. And i can change only the label? Basically i want to keep the tab and change the visualforce reference only.

Is there a way to change the link?

[image]

Comment: Can't you delete it and recreate it?

Comment: @doga For sure, but then i must to update my 20 apps manually ;)

Comment: I guess it wouldn't take much time to update your apps?

Comment: @doga It takes to much time to edit the order of the tabs in each app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it would seem that this cannot be edited via the UI, I can confirm it can be edited via Force.com IDE. Or you can just recreate it manually, which maybe easier if your not using Force.com IDE already.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, nice to know Andrew. Yes i use Force.com IDE, and it is of course much easier to change the content over there. We have more than 100 profiles and bout 20 apps, so to change all that stuff manually is a hard work :) Thank you!

Comment: Very welcome! :)

Comment: Outstanding spot Andy